# What does "that split" mean?

Tags: word-usage, terminology, finance

I read an [article](https://www.theverge.com/2017/7/24/16020878/google-ceo-sundar-pichai-alphabet-board-of-directors) about Sundar Pichai Google CEO.

> ...
>
> Since then, things have gone well at Google under Pichai's leadership,
>   while things at Alphabet have been a bit more rocky. Some of those
>   bumps can be attributed to the whole idea behind Alphabet in the first
>   place: making businesses like Fiber, X and self-driving cars.
>
> **That split** elevated Pichai to CEO and perhaps allowed him to institute a little more focus inside Google.

Can anyone help me to understand what does mean "That split" exactly?

Is there another expression instead of?

Comment: What does the dictionary say??

Comment: The split of Alphabet into parts.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

***[Split](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/split-up.asp)*** or *split-up* in financial jargon is used to indicate the separation of different entities from a single original company. The sense is that Pichai benefited from the split (the separation of Google from other sisters companies) as he probably could focus more on Google activities:

> [Larry Page](https://www.krishaweb.com/blog/google-inc-will-be-one-of-the-many-entities-under-alphabet-inc) told that they are creating a new holding company named – Alphabet Inc. Google search and all other business will be the ***subsidiary entities under the head of Alphabet***.
>
> Calico (Focused on longevity), Fiber (Internet Access), Google, Google Ventures (VC investing), Google Capital (investment fund), Google X, Life Science (the glucose sensing contact lens) and Nest are going to be the ***different entities under the belt of Alphabet***.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the context, 'That Split' refers to Google reorganising its interests into Alphabet Inc. in August 2015.

Answer (score 1):

"split" refers to "splitting off" / separating / re-organizing the non-google related things out of the Google company into Alphabet. It's not an idiom, it's meant quite literally here.